# recursive method for flipping card

Tags: java, recursion

in java - if i have an index card with the letter C written on side, and S on the other. how do i write a recursive method that print each sessoin of dropping the cards with C's and S's. for example: if i drop it 4 times,all possible ways to drop it ara as follows in this specific order:

SCSC
SCSS
SSCC
SSCS
SSSC
SSSS

Comment: May be `if (m <= 0)` ?

Comment: i have tried, didn't work

Comment: 0b0110 is 6 in decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually rather simple:

```
public void flip(List<String> items, int length, String prefix)
{
    if (prefix.length() == length) {
        items.add(prefix);
        return;
    }
    increments(items, length, prefix + 'C');
    increments(items, length, prefix + 'S');
}
```

As you can see, there are two recursive calls, one for the 'C' character and one for the 'S' character, and the recursion base case is when the prefix length is the length specified (4, in your case)

Call like so:

```
List<String> inc = new LinkedList<>();
increments(inc, 4, "");
for (String s : inc)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Which outputs:

```
CCCC
CCCS
CCSC
CCSS
CSCC
CSCS
CSSC
CSSS
SCCC
SCCS
SCSC
SCSS
SSCC
SSCS
SSSC
SSSS
```

This method can easily be generalised for any array of characters:

```
public void increments(List<String> items, int length, 
                       String prefix, char[] chars)
{
    if (prefix.length() == length) {
        items.add(prefix);
        return;
    }
    for (char c : chars)
        increments(items, length, prefix + c, chars);
}

List<String> inc = new LinkedList<>();
increments(inc, 4, "", new char[] {'C', 'S'});
for (String s : inc)
    System.out.println(s);
```

This yields the same output.

*Note: this method has a high complexity, O(pow(chars.length, length)), so attempting to run it with a large input size will take a (very) long time to complete.*

---

### `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` Approach

As requested:

```
public void increments_ibs(List<String> items, int n, int i)
{
    if (i >= Math.pow(2, n))
        return;

    String bs = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    while (bs.length() < n)
         bs = "0" + bs;
    items.add(bs.replaceAll("0", "C").replaceAll("1", "S"));

    increments_ibs(items, n, i+1);
}
```

This is essentially an iterative algorithm written recursively.

Comment: thanks Der Flatulator your answer is working good. but is there an easy way to solve the problem ysing binary number like 
Andrew Schuster said? i have tried, and i think it's more simpler.

 public int Flip(int n) {
        n = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
        flip1(n);
        return n;

    }

    public static int flip1(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            String f = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
            
        }
    }
i just need to know how to replace 0's with 'C' and 1's with 'S'

Comment: @user2956470 You wont be able to write it any simpler than the recursive method listed. If you think about it, it is binary recursion. The first call is the '0'/'C', the second is the '1'/'S'. This would be more apparent with an iterative approach, but it would be more code.

Comment: @user2956470 Just made added an `Integer.toBinaryString` approach to the answer, as you can see it's not as neat as the proper recursive approach, but it's there for the taking.

Answer (score 0):

So this problem is actually a lot simpler if you realize that the card flipping is actually just counting upwards by one in binary.

With that in mind, you can just keep track of an *X* bit long number (where *X* is the number of cards you want to keep track of) and then print the cards by checking to see where there are 1's (`S`) or 0's (`C`).

After you do that, check to see if all of the positions have 1's.  If they do, exit recursion.  If they don't, add one to the number and run the function again.

**Edit**

If you know the number of bits in the number beforehand (something easy enough to calculate) you could use bit shifting (`>>` will be the best here).  So for instance, you could have a quick for loop to go through the number and check each position.

```
int cardTracker = 0b0110; //this is 6 in decimal
char[] toPrint = new char[4];

//The 4 here is the length of the binary number
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    //This if statement checks if the last number is 0 or 1
    if((cardTracker >> ((4 - 1) - i) % 2  == 0)
    {
        toPrint[i] = 'C';
    }
    else
    {
        toPrint[i] = 'S';
    }
}
```

The above will print the following if you were to print the contents of `toPrint`.

```
CSSC
```

Hopefully you can use the above and adapt it to your code for the recursive problem.

Comment: yes i have tried your way but how can i replace an integer within a char or how to find the place of an intejer and print at the right plase? without replacing.

Comment: If you know the length of the binary number beforehand, you can use bit shifting to check the last digit.

Comment: I added an example of how you could interpret the numbers.

Comment: The card tracker will be written by the user ؟ you put 5 in decimal. how about if the user want to print 5? or 6? i mean it have to change isn't it?

Comment: That's the reason I included an **example**.  Seeing as I don't know the scope of your problem nor the expected inputs, I tried to make it as general as possible.  The above code can be adapted fairly easily to just about any use you want for it.  It's just a snippet.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your last comment.
thank you Mr.Andrew i wish i can vote to your answer, but my reputation is less than required.